# Send Mass email, with text properties such as Font, Size, Bold and Underline carrying over from the text box to the email

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that sends mass emails with personalisation (replacing the AX markers with personalised text)

I would also like to have the font and font size carried over from the Text Box (the font's name is Mary Ann) as well as the spaces between paragraphs and text being in bold or underlined where I've done so in the text box. However I receive a run time error 5 message when I run the code

My code is below:

```
Sub Send_Talent_Review_Briefing_email_Test_3()
   
   'Change code to work for my sheet
   
     'Declare variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim emailTo As String
    Dim emailSubject As String
    Dim emailBody As String
    Dim textBox As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim char As String
    
    'Set workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Talent_Review_Briefing")
    
    'Set Outlook application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    'Get the text box value
    textBox = ws.Shapes("Talent_Review_Briefing_Email").TextFrame.Characters.Text
    
    'Get the last row with data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Loop through the rows
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        'Get the email address, subject and body from the columns
        emailTo = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        emailSubject = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        emailBody = textBox
        
        'Replace the placeholders with the values from the cells
        emailBody = Replace(emailBody, "A1", ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        emailBody = Replace(emailBody, "A4", ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)
        emailBody = Replace(emailBody, "A5", ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)
        emailBody = Replace(emailBody, "A6", ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)
        emailBody = Replace(emailBody, "A7", ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)
        emailBody = Replace(emailBody, "A8", ws.Cells(i, 8).Value)
        emailBody = Replace(emailBody, "A9", ws.Cells(i, 9).Value)
        
        'Create a new email object
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        'Set the email properties
        With olMail
            .To = emailTo
            .subject = emailSubject
            .BodyFormat = 2 'HTML format
            .HTMLBody = "<p>" 'Start a paragraph tag
            
            'Loop through the characters in the email body
            For j = 1 To Len(emailBody)
                'Get the current character
                char = Mid(emailBody, j, 1)
                
                'If the character is a line break, close the paragraph tag and start a new one
                If char = vbNewLine Then
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</p><pstyle='margin:10px;'>"
                Else
                    'Copy the font properties from the text box to the email body
                    'With ws.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters(j, 1).Font
                    With ws.Shapes("Talent_Review_Briefing_Email").TextFrame.Characters(j, 1).Text
                        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<span style='font-family:Mary Ann;font-size:12pt;"
                        If .Bold Then .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "font-weight:bold;"
                        If .Italic Then .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "font-style:italic;"
                        If .Underline Then .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "text-decoration:underline;"
                    End With
                End If
            Next j
            
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</p>" 'Close the last paragraph tag
            .Display 'Show the email before sending
            '.Send 'Uncomment this line to send the email
        End With
    Next i
    
    'Clean up
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

My Text is over 255 characters so I can't ask the Text Box to pull from a specified cell

I have also edited the Alt Text for my Text Box to be "Talent_Review_Briefing" and made the relevant changes in the code (I think!) however it still gives the same error message

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `TextFrame.Characters(j, 1).Text` is a String and cannot be used in a `With`-statement.

Comment: Hi, are you able to give an example of what the code should look like? Apologies I'm quite new to VBA!

Comment: You're reading the character formatting information from the textbox, but you already replaced the tags "A1", "A4" etc in `emailBody` with other text, so your `emailBody` string is no longer aligned with the text in the textbox....  (unless the replacement text was the exact same length as the replaced tags)